# How to get the visitor's IP address from the DNS request?

Tags: python, dns, cdn

I am running my own DNS name server which I have developed in python. I have a registered domain name say "abc.in". The name servers of the domain are set to my computer's IP address (given by ISP). Now whenever anyone access the domain name I am getting the visitor's ISP's IP address. I want to get the visitor's IP address. Actually I want to make a small CDN like project, also I am not able to find any good source of information. Is it possible to get the visitor's IP address, I am developing it in Python ?

I had read in [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com)'s blog that they get the visitor's geographic information (IP address) from the initial DNS lookups.

Comment: How are you accessing the visitor's ISP's IP address?  Also, how do you know it's the ISP's address?

Comment: The user's computer will lookup your hostname on whatever DNS servers it's configured to use. Normally, this will be the ISP's own DNS server, which will in turn lookup the address on your server. There's no way to get the user's IP if this is the case; their machine doesn't contact your DNS server at all.

Comment: @Wooble : I know what is the scenario but I had read in CloudFlare's blog that they (some how) get the visitor's IP that is why I posted the question.

Comment: Maybe link to the actual blog post?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/How-does-CloudFlare-work the 6th paragraph.

Comment: @vedarthk, Anycast does not need to know the IP address of the end user, it advertises the same address ranges on several different gateway borders in order for the one closest to the end user to be used for routing. [Would you like to know more?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi : I was not aware of Anycast, but I am not able to understand which address ranges are advertised ? and on which gateway borders ?

Comment: @vedarthk, that's quite simple actually: the routers on the Internet have to decide which path your packets will take, and they do so according to address ranges advertised through the [Border Gateway Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol). Basically, it amounts to *to reach an IP within this range, take a left; within that other range, take a right*. If one advertises the same address range on several geographically distinct routers, the one closest to the sender of the packets will be chosen for routing because it's the first one the packet encounters on its path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket function in python. Like following.

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo
```

Comment: That gives me the IP address of the visitor's ISP and not the IP address of the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is simply not possible. You'll always get the connection from the resolver, not the final client.

Comment: Except of course if the final client uses his/her own recursive resolver, which is rather rare.

Comment: I was not aware of Anycast that is why I posted this question. Also I know that I get the address of the resolver. I was curious if there is some other way around.

Comment: Anycast has nothing to do with your original question? The only nameservers I know of to actually officially use anycast are a few of the roots, and that's got nothing to do with ISP resolution.

Comment: @modelnine, CloudFlare relies on Anycast, so the question indeed mentioned it, albeit indirectly.

Comment: There's no need for anycast to get an approximate geolocation, thats what a GeoIP lookup on the connecting provider resolver accomplishes, and it's what e.g. an authoritative bind can implement already, @FrėdėricHamidi.